# Maximum Length of Currency field with its Decimal Places Component

Tags: fields, currency

What is the Maximum Length Of Currency Field with its Decimal Places Component. ?

Answer (score 1):

Maximum  length of Currency Field length is 18 digits and minimum value can be 1 digit.

Maximum length of decimal places is  17 digits and  minimum value can be 0 digit.

Total Length  of  Length Properties and  Decimal Places can only be 18 digits for numeric field.